# Am I using virtualenv wrong or is this a limitation of it?

Tags: python, virtualenv

So I used `virtualenv` to define environments for a number of projects I am working on. I defined the `virtualenv` python as being version 3.4. Eventually, my global python was upgraded from 3.4.0 to 3.4.3. This proved to be a problem because the `virtualenv` was dependent on the global binaries (the contents of `/lib/python3.4` in my `virtualenv` is actually just links to the global binaries), and these aren't defined up to their minor versions. In other words, when the upgrade was done, the contents of the binary folder `/usr/lib/python3.4` was replaced. This is because python doesn't install things separately in 3.4.0 and 3.4.3 but only into a single folder named `/usr/lib/python3.4`. Since the python executable in my `virtualenv` was 3.4.0, there were obviously compatibility issues with the 3.4.3 binaries (it would fail to load `ctypes` which prevented just about anything python dependent to run). The only fix to this I've found is to downgrade my global python installation, but this feels "dirty". What if I had one project running 3.4.0 and another running 3.4.3 ? Is there no way to make them work in parallel on the same machine given that only one binary folder can exist for any 3.4.x installation ?

I'm trying to understand if I'm missing something obvious here or if this is a common problem with `virtualenv`, given that I've heard quite a few people complain about issues with binares when using `virtualenv`.

In the future, is there anyway of telling `virtualenvwrapper` to copy the binaries rather than link to them ?

Comment: Is the problem with Python 3.4.3 being incompatible with your code or is it just the virtualenv failing (re-creating the virtualenv and re-installing everything inside fixes it)?

Comment: The problem is not with my code. Even just loading up a python interpreter inside the virtual env will fail whenever I try to load basic libraries. So things go wrong well before the details of my code enter the picture. This is really about running an executable with the wrong binaries linked to it.

Comment: What if you create a new virtualenv and run Python 3.4.3 in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtualenvs were not desiged to be portable, both across machines or across Python versions.

This means upgrading Python versions sometimes breaks virtualenvs. You need to recreate them and reinstall everything inside of it (run this in your virtualenv root):

```
# Save a list of what you had installed
pip freeze > freeze.txt

# Trash the entire virtualenv
deactivate
rm -rf lib/ bin/ share/ man/ include/ .Python pip-selfcheck.json

# Create it anew
virtualenv .

# Install all libraries you had before
pip install -r freeze.txt
```

Comment: "Upgrading Python versions sometimes breaks virtualenvs." This answers my question. I'm aware that I can recreate each virtualenv individually with an upgraded python, but it seems to me that doing so defeats the whole purpose of using virtualenv in the first place... But if indeed upgrading python breaks virutalenv then it does seem to me that this is a severe limitation of it.

Comment: Virtualenvs were not desiged to be portable, both across machines or across Python versions. It is a known drawback, but doesn't defeat its purpose.

Comment: Gotcha. I though that since it allowed you to specify which python version to use that meant it was supposed to be able to handle a global change in python versions while keeping a locally static one. I guess not then and it's only about handling external module versions. Thanks for the help. Could you just add that comment in your answer btw ? Because this really gets to the heart of what I'm asking. I can then accept the answer.

Comment: If they are not portable then what's the point of using them? Do they add any value? One could have used `anaconda` or `miniconda` which are far better.

Comment: @hafiz031 Conda envs are not portable either. Virtualenvs and Conda envs serve the same purpose: Isolate environments from another. Conda vs Virtualenvs is a matter of taste and project requirements, neither one is *better* per se.